# java.io.FileInputStream cannot be converted to java.io.File error while executing jmeter

Tags: jmeter, fileinputstream, maven-compiler-plugin

I am trying to execute the following snippet in Java using Maven.

```
    StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();
    JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/path/jmeter.properties");
    JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("/path/apache-jmeter-3.3");
    JMeterUtils.initLogging();
    JMeterUtils.initLocale();

    // Initialize JMeter SaveService
    SaveService.loadProperties();

    // Load existing .jmx Test Plan
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/path/jmeter_file.jmx");


    HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(in);
    in.close();
```

When I run mvn clean install, I get following error:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project <project-name>: Compilation failure
    [ERROR] /path/javafile.java:[40,54] incompatible types: java.io.FileInputStream cannot be converted to java.io.File
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project <project-name>: Compilation failure
    /path/javafile.java:[40,54] incompatible types: java.io.FileInputStream cannot be converted to java.io.File

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

Error occurs on the following line:
        HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(in);

Comment: thanks Dmitri, I have tried the same but while writing the code, it is expecting FileInputStream parameter for SaveService.loadTree() method. I have also done a re-import of jar files but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeter version 3.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-3.3) [SaveService.loadTree() method](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/5c9dd1632e92ca197f818a1ee04f8f8af4bbc42e/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/save/SaveService.java#L421) seems to be accepting [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html), not FileInputStream, so:

change these lines:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/path/jmeter_file.jmx");
HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(in);
in.close();
```

to this one:

```
HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(new File("/path/jmeter_file.jmx"));
```